# problem to insert inkscape pdf into latex

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert the `1.pdf_tex` which was generated by Inkscape into my article and I always get this error message:

> ! Package keyval Error: page undefined.
>       See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
>       Type H  for immediate help.
>       ...
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/1.pdf (no BoundingBox
>             ).
>       l.55 ...graphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{1.pdf}}
>       %
>
> ! Package keyval Error: page undefined.
>       .......
>       ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/1.pdf (no BoundingBox
>        ).
>
> l.55 ...graphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{1.pdf}}
>        %

I have two documents (`1.pdf_tex` and `1.pdf`) in a directory `images\` and I've already put

```
\usepackge{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

at the very beginning of my document. Here is how I insert the `1.pdf_tex`:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
  \input{images/1.pdf_tex}
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
```

I really want to know why I can't compile and get my final document.

#### `1.pdf_tex`

[image: part 1][image: part 2]

save file:[image: save file]

Comment: I do not know what `=\unitlength` is. But if the pdf page has no BoundingBox, this looks like an error in how it was generated?

Comment: can you show us 1.pdf_tex ?

Comment: ok, thank both of u! i will show u 1.pdf_tex

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `,page=1` and all subsequent `\put` commands which have included repeatedly the input PDF.

This is probably an error of the Inkscape tool, probably this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1417470

You can use next command to delete all the puts minus the first

```
  sed -i '/page=[2-9]\|page=1[0-9]/d' *tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't solve it and you haven't realize yet. You have a typo in

```
\usepackge{graphicx}
```

Has to be

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Why not add this to your other answer as a side comment? Based on the error messages that were reported, I'm guessing this is not the issue (and hence doesn't answer the question); presumably it's just at typo in writing this up on TeX.SX.

Comment: The reason why I didn't add as a side comment or edited is that it has nothing to do with the other problem